# SVG Text Fill Using Pattern Not Working In Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I am working with SVG. I'm using an external image within a pattern definition and then referencing that pattern as the fill for my text.

After the latest Chrome release, I am unable to see my fill.

This is not my code but can be used for the reproduction:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="p1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="32" height="32">
      <image xlink:href="http://phrogz.net/tmp/alphaball-small.png" width="32" height="32" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="p2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
      <image xlink:href="http://phrogz.net/tmp/grid.gif" width="10" height="10" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <text x="20" y="170" fill="url(#p1)">
    Hello
    <tspan x="20" y="350" fill="url(#p2)">Wo<tspan fill="url(#p1)">r</tspan>ld</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

To view the code open it up in a browser context like a fiddle or an SVG compiler within Chrome / Safari or Firefox. You will see it does not work in Chrome as of yesterday.

I have tried moving the pattern definition around and applying svg visual attributes like `preserveAspectRatio` without any results. Has anybody encountered this and is there a solution. I can't use masking as a solution because the code is running within monogramming logic so the element has to be `<text>`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand, how is the above fiddle not a minimal reproducible code snippet? And why did you delete my comment?

Comment: As proven by 15+ years StackOverflow history your **external** JSFiddle _will_ be gone in the future. Making your question here useless for others. That's is why StackOverflow wants you to add code as a SO Snippet. It was also proven in those 15+ years, questions with SO Snippets get more and better answers. I might have answered your question, but I don't go looking for code on external sites. # And no one can delete _your_ comments.

Comment: That is not my fiddle and has been around for just about as long as Stack Overflow which is also cloud based and has indefinite resources. Hopefully the CDN images used in the example code does not go stale but I can't make any promises.